# trivial solution for an initial value problem of homogeneous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following initial value problem

$$ y^{(n)} + P_{(n-1)}(x) y^{(n-1)} + ... + P_1(x)y' + P_0(x) y = 0 $$

$$y(x_0)=y'(x_0) = ... = y^{(n-1)}(x_0) = 0$$

I know if I take $y=0$, then it satisfies this ODE, and thus it must be the only one by uniqueness. Is this enough to prove that the trivial solution $y=0$ is the only one for this IVP?

Comment: How smooth are your coefficients?

Comment: differentiable..

Comment: You need to know the uniqueness theorem is usually stated for ode of the form $\dot y = f(t, y)$. Thus, you have to use uniqueness for systems of first order linear differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

Put the $n$th order linear homogeneous equation into a system which I will write as
\begin{align}
\dot X(t) = A(t)X(t) \ \ (*)
\end{align}
where $X:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose we have proven existence of solutions for $(*)$, then we know there exists $X$ such that
\begin{align}
X(t) = X(t_0) +  \int^t_{t_0} A(s)X(s)\ ds = \int^t_{t_0} A(s)X(s)\ ds
\end{align}
for $t, t_0 \in [a, b]$. Then it follows
\begin{align}
||X(t)|| \leq \int^t_{t_0} || A(s)X(s)|| \ ds \leq \sup_{s\in [a, b]}||A(s)||_\infty \int^t_{t_0} ||X(s)||\ ds = C\int^t_{t_0} ||X(s)||\ ds.
\end{align}
Using basic Gronwall's inequality we conclude
\begin{align}
||X(t)|| = 0 
\end{align}
for all $t \in [a, b]$.